# Create One Hot Encoding Column Based on Part of the other Column's Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have this kind of dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1894, 1976, 1995, 2001, 1993]})
```

**The current `dataframe`**

```
    year
0   1894
1   1976
2   1995
3   2001
4   1993
```

How can I effectively add one hot encoding columns so that the dataframe would look like this.

**The expected `dataframe`**

```
    year    1800s   1900s   2000s
0   1894      1       0       0
1   1976      0       1       0
2   1995      0       1       0
3   2001      0       0       1
4   1993      0       1       0
```

I already tried the code below and it worked. But I think there is a better solution, can you recommend me what function can I use ? Thank you!

**The code**

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(str)

df['1800s'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[:2] == '18' else 0)
df['1900s'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[:2] == '19' else 0)
df['2000s'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x[:2] == '20' else 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use integer division for first 2 digits with [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), rename columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and last use [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for add to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['year'] // 100).add_suffix('00s'))
print (df)
   year  1800s  1900s  2000s
0  1894      1      0      0
1  1976      0      1      0
2  1995      0      1      0
3  2001      0      0      1
4  1993      0      1      0

print (df['year'] // 100)
0    18
1    19
2    19
3    20
4    19
Name: year, dtype: int64

print (pd.get_dummies(df['year'] // 100).add_suffix('00s'))
   1800s  1900s  2000s
0      1      0      0
1      0      1      0
2      0      1      0
3      0      0      1
4      0      1      0
```